# Read data values from text file along with number of rows and columns in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a data file in `.txt` format with 7 rows and 4 columns.
I am using following code to read these values:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
 int N=7, i;
 double x[7], y[7], p[7], q[7];
 FILE *f1;
 f1=fopen("data.txt","r");
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     fscanf(f1,"%lf %lf %lf %lf", &p[i], &q[i], &x[i], &y[i]);
 fclose(f1);
}
```

Here N is the number of rows in the data file, which I know in advance.

Is there any way to read the number of rows in the data file, so that I can generalize this code for any data file without knowing the value of N in advance.

NOTE: The number of columns is not changing between different data files.

Comment: fscanf returns  a value.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count the lines yourself (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733105/c-function-that-counts-lines-in-file) for example), and then rewind the file pointer to the start of the file, to actually parse it, now that you found `N`.

To reset the pointer to the start of the file, do this:

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

---

Another way is to find out the size of your data and do some calculations, like this:

```
% Read the vector size
d = fread (fid, 1, 'int');
vecsizeof = 1 * 4 + d * 4;

% Get the number of vectrors
fseek (fid, 0, 1);
a = 1;
bmax = ftell (fid) / vecsizeof;
b = bmax;

if nargin >= 2
  if length (bounds) == 1
    b = bounds;

  elseif length (bounds) == 2
    a = bounds(1);
    b = bounds(2);    
  end
end

assert (a >= 1);
if b > bmax
  b = bmax;
end

if b == 0 | b < a
  v = [];
  fclose (fid);
  return;
end

% compute the number of vectors that are really read and go in starting positions
n = b - a + 1;
fseek (fid, (a - 1) * vecsizeof, -1);
```

Relevant [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) code can be found [here](http://corpus-texmex.irisa.fr/ivecs_read.m).

Comment: Will you be kind enough to write the full answer here instead of redirecting me to another link?

Comment: I did my best for that answer @RD017, hope that helps! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* count the number of rows in the given text table */  
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    int count = 0;  
    FILE* ptr = fopen("D:\\test.txt","r");  
    if (ptr==NULL)  
    {  
        printf("no such file.");  
        return 0;  
    }  

    /* Assuming that test.txt has content in below  
       format with 4 row and 3 column  
       NAME    AGE   CITY  
       aaa     21    xxxxx  
       bbb     23    yyyyy  
       ccc     24    zzzzz  
       ddd     25    qqqqqq */  

    char* buffer[100];  

    while (fscanf(ptr,"%*s %*s %s ",buffer)==1)  
    {  
        count++;  
        //printf("%s\n", buffer);  
    }  

    // if there are column name present in the table in first row  
    printf("count = %d", (count-1));  

    return 0;  
}
```