# Why is fgets resetting my double pointer element?

Tags: c

I'm trying to store an array of string in a double pointer but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

```c
char **pointerA;
char *pointerB;
int count;

FILE* file = fopen("textfile.ini", "r");

pointerA = (char **) malloc (sizeof(*pointerA));
pointerB = (char *) malloc (sizeof(*pointerB));

while(fgets(pointerB, 200, file) !== NULL)
{
    pointerA = (char **)realloc(pointerA, sizeof(char *) * (strlen(pointerB) + 1));
    pointerA[count] = pointerB;  
    count++;
}

fclose(file);
```

I expect every element to only store it's own string but it seems like all the element is storing the last string.

Answer (score 0):

`pointerB = (char *) malloc (sizeof(*pointerB));`

you allocate 1 `char` and read in the `fgets` up to 200.

## edit

It has to be something like this

```
char **pointerA;
char *pointerB;

#define MAXSTRING   200

FILE* file = fopen("textfile.ini", "r");

pointerA = NULL;

size_t nlines = 0;
do
{
    pointerB = malloc(MAXSTRING);
    pointerA = realloc(pointerA, sizeof(char *) * (nlines+1));
    pointerA[nlines] = pointerB;  
    nlines++;
}while(pointerB & fgets(pointerB, , file) !== NULL)

fclose(file);
```

Comment: So what should I be doing? I don't quite understand where I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate each element of pointerA like so :

```
int nbLines = 10; //number of lines to read in file
char** pointerA = ( char** ) malloc ( sizeof ( char* ) * nbLines ); //allocate 2D array. Each element points to another string
for ( int i = 0; i < nbLines; ++i ) {
    char line [ 200 ];
    fgets ( line , 200 , file ); //get a line from the file
    pointerA [ i ] = ( char* ) malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * strlen ( line ) ); //allocate a string with the size of that line
    pointerA [ i ] = line; 

}
```

Comment: That's basically hard coding. I want something that dynamically changes when there are more lines added to the text file

Comment: you can have a function that counts the number of lines in the file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733105/c-function-that-counts-lines-in-file

You unfortunately can't do better in C language without keeping your code relatively simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to work with n strings you could do something like this:

```
int cur_lines = 0;
char **pointerA = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (cur_lines + 1));
char line [200];
while(fgets(line, 200, file))
    pointerA[cur_lines] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200); 
    strcpy(pointerA[cur_lines],line); 
    cur_lines += 1;
    pointerA = realloc(pointerA, sizeof(char *) * (cur_lines + 1));
}
```

Of course you should check that the results of the `malloc` and `realloc` are not `NULL` before using these variables, usually you don't directly overwrite the pointer you are using whith a `realloc` but create a new one instead and overwrite the old one if it's not `NULL` to avoid having memory leaks.

If you want better performance you shouldn't increase `pointerA` by only 1 at each loop but more than that (usually double) and keep a counter of used spaces. Also keep in mind that having a line of `200` chars means that the maximum line length is actually `199` since the last character is `\0`.

The problem with this approach is that you'll have one last unused `malloc`'d space that you need to take care of later.